# Bootstrap grid putting text on top of each other instead of next to

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't get my bootstrap grid code to place the work test on the left of Choose your bicycle. instead test is in the line above Choose your bicycle. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='formApp'>
<head>
<title>Bicycle App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>

        <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>&nbsp;{{"Andy's Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
</div>
</div>
    </div><!--Header Container-->
    </div>
<div class="bikeSelector">
        <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-3">test</div>
    <div class='col-offset-3 col-md-6'>

Choose your bicycle
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I see them in one line.

Comment: Most likely your bootstrap is not being loaded preperly..

Comment: Check if you're opening in the correct resolution as well. Md will work fine starting at 720px to 939px...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='formApp'>
<head>
<title>Bicycle App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>

        <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>&nbsp;{{"Andy's Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
</div>
</div>
    </div><!--Header Container-->
    </div>
<div class="bikeSelector">
        <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-3">test</div>
    <div class='col-offset-3 col-md-6'>

Choose your bicycle
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked, but I can't see the differences in code. Can you explain to me what you fixed to get it working?

Comment: I've included the bootstrap here: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Wow I feel stupid. Not only did I forget to bower install bootstrap, but also I didn't even import it. It's the simplest mistakes that always get you lol

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're wrapping your text in a `div`; `Divs` display as block elements by default. You either need to wrap them in an inline element (`p`, `span`) or make those divs `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`

**Example:**

```
<div class="bikeSelector">
    <div class="container">
        <div class='row'>
            <p class="col-md-3">test</p>

            <p class='col-offset-3 col-md-6'>
                Choose your bicycle
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**or in CSS:**

```
.bikeSelector .row > div {display: inline-block}
```